# TypeError: state is not iterable on react and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So i just learned redux and tried to make a simple list with redux and react.
but when i click on the button to add item to the list i got an error "state is not iterable"

here is my code

reducer

```
function manageList(state = { items: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return { list: [...state, action.payload] };
    case RESET_LIST:
      return {
        item: [...state, []],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

action

```
export const ADD_ITEM = "ADD_ITEM";
export const RESET_LIST = "RESET_LIST";

export function addItem(text) {
  return { type: ADD_ITEM, payload: text };
}

export function resetList() {
  return { type: RESET_LIST };
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're spreading an object inside an array, to fix that you should spread the items property inside an array:

```
function manageList(state = { items: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return { list: [...state.items, action.payload] };
    case RESET_LIST:
      return {
        items: [...state.items, []],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I think also that you should replace `list` and `item` by `items` :

```
function manageList(state = { items: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return { items: [...state.items, action.payload] };
    case RESET_LIST:
      return {
        items: [...state.items, []],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: its not working, the first time i add item its works, then if i click to add another item its says "state.items is not iterable"

Comment: please check my second suggestion since you're changing the property in each case so keep it as `items`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should spread them as "state.items" not as just "state".

Like this:

```
item: [...state.items,[]]
```

Not like this:

```
item: [...state,[]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export const commentReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COMMENT_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case COMMENT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        comment: [...state.comment, action.payload],
      };
    case COMMENT_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

You should use `item: [...state.items,[]]`  Because you just want to change items from the state.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!